# Logback conditional ("isDefined") appender creation not working

Tags: java, logback, appender, janino

I have something like the following in my logback.xml (I've simplified it down to just the relevant parts):

```
  <if condition='isDefined("REQUEST_LOG_DIR")'>
    <then>
      <appender name="requests" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${REQUEST_LOG_DIR}/requests.log</file>
        <encoder><pattern>%msg%n</pattern></encoder>
      </appender>
    </then>
  </if>

  <logger name="application.requests" additivity="false" level="INFO">
    <if condition='isDefined("REQUEST_LOG_DIR")'>
      <then>
          <appender-ref ref="requests" />
      </then>
    </if>
  </logger>
```

If I run my application with REQUEST_LOG_DIR defined, it works as expected: Messages I log to this logger end up in ${REQUEST_LOG_DIR}/requests.log.

However, if I run with my application with REQUEST_LOG_DIR undefined, it ends up creating a **REQUEST_LOG_DIR_IS_UNDEFINED** directory containing an empty requests.log file.

The fact that the file stays empty indicates that the second piece of conditional logic is working as expected to not add the appender to the logger when REQUEST_LOG_DIR is undefined.

However, I don't understand why the directory is getting created. If REQUEST_LOG_DIR is undefined (which it obviously is, given the name of the directory), then the first conditional should be stopping the FileAppender from being instantiated.

Comment: did the answer help you, btw?

Comment: @Eugene, thank you, your answer was very helpful for understanding that this is the expected behavior and saving time further investigating. Unfortunately, in the real application I am using a RollingFileAppender, not a basic FileAppender as in my example (which I did for brevity because I didn't think it matters), and the comments say that "SiftingAppender doesn't work well with RollingFileAppender."

Comment: @Eugene, I am going to end up attaching the appender to the logger programmatically instead of in XML which should be fine and allow me to use conditional logic that works as expected

Comment: I know yes, but the answer targets your question, exactly. So in case you have a different one - you might want to ask another one, then.

Comment: yeah, you can do that - right. But just notice that once you move to "large scale", this isn't really a very portable solution :( anyway, if you have other questions, you can tag me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `FileAppender` [is not lazy](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-202). There are ways to work around that, partially.

You can wrap your file into :

```
 <appender name="wrapper" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">

  ....
```

I remember that there were cases where I did not liked this, but can't remember anymore now.